# Laravel - How to Add another Join to get multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

hello here I have 1 join table and here is my join statement. but i only have one join statement and it is only getting 1 table i need another 4 tables to join or get so how can i do it on this sql join query

lets assume that i need to add these tables: `products` , `stocks`, `foods`, `beverage`

my query statement for join

```
$getairId = DB::table('aircrafts')
  ->join('movies','movies.aircraft_id','=','aircrafts.aircraft_id')
  ->select('movies.*')
  ->where('aircrafts.aircraft_id','=', $airid)
  ->get();
```

how to add another join

Answer (score 0):

I am new To laravel But i have written the two joins to retrive `created_by` and `updated_by` Name in categories table With name in the users table

here is my query

```
$result = DB::table('categories')
            ->leftJoin('users as created_table', 'created_table.id', '=', 'categories.created_by')
            ->leftJoin('users as updated_table', 'updated_table.id', '=', 'categories.updated_by')
            ->select('categories.*','created_table.name as created_by','updated_table.name as updated_by')
            ->paginate(3);
```

Please Add as much of joins and customize to your requirement

Adding Screen Shots

`categories` Table Data

[image]

`users` Table Data

[image]

Blade file to disaply the data

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Category 
                    <strong style="float:right;"><a href="{{ url('/category/add') }}">Add</a>  | </strong>
                 </div>

                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
                    <tr>
                            <td>#</td>
                            <td>Category Name</td>
                            <td>Created Date</td>
                            <td>Created By</td>
                            <td>Updated By</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $sno = 0 ?>
                    @foreach($result as $data_key => $data)
                    <!-- {{ $sno++ }}  -->

                    <tr>
                            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                            <td>{!! $data->category_name !!}</td>
                            <td>{!! $data->created_at !!}</td>
                            <td>{!! $data->created_by !!}</td>
                            <td>{!! $data->updated_by !!}</td>
                    </tr>

                    @endforeach
                </table>

                <div class="card-header">
                    {{ $result->links() }}
                 </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and then attaching the screen shot of the category list[image: n]

Comment: hey sir thank you for your response. can i see the output or the data that has been fetch? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

or you can go for eloquent relationship [laravel eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships). This will help you if you wanted to use less join queries.

EX. You can fetch aircraft detail like this

add this function on your aircraft eloquent

```
 public function movie()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Movie','aircraft_id','aircraft_id');
    }
```

and you can use it like this in your controller

```
$getairId = DB::table('aircrafts')->with('movie')->get();
```